# TinyMCE shows error in the editor

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, django-tinymce

I have used tinyMCE for my project. but now I am getting a below error

This domain is not registered with TinyMCE Cloud. Start a free trial to discover our premium cloud services and pro support

Can anyone know how to get rid of this error message? without using paid service from tinyMCE?

Answer (score 16):

Thank you @Ignacio Ara. A free API key is valid only for 30 days.
I have used CSS property display none for the class .mce-notification.mce-in
that resolved my problem.

Comment: Could You Please Provide The CSS?

Comment: @Heisenberg `.tox-notification { display: none !important }`

Answer (score 15):

I solved my problem used this function.

```
_tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  init_instance_callback : function(editor) {
    var freeTiny = document.querySelector('.tox .tox-notification--in');
   freeTiny.style.display = 'none';
  }
 });
```

Comment: As no other solution has helped me, this should be the accepted one. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

I have solved my problem with the use

```
<script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: As my edit was rejected, for everyone that needs 5.0 use this: `<script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/[API_KEY_HERE]/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>`

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a JS framework like VueJS, you can use the `tinymce-script-src` attribute to use a non-cloud version of `tinymce.min.js` to avoid the error message but still have the framework functionality.

Example using a locally stored non-cloud file:

```
<editor tinymce-script-src="tinymce/tinymce.min.js" ... />
```

You can see why this works in the Vue implementation here:
https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-vue/blob/9ef5d30ff68c5428940ff4722bdb257e6079bc7e/src/main/ts/components/Editor.ts#L94

Comment: I've downloaded script from https://download.tiny.cloud/tinymce/community/tinymce_6.0.1.zip?_ga=2.237622659.2077796099.1650437738-153142498.1650437738 and it works

Comment: @PawełMoskal, that's the "TinyMCE SDK" and the link you provided can be found on the cloud site: https://www.tiny.cloud/get-tiny/

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I've added another answer to detail how to override this in an Angular project

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you're using TinyMCE getting the file from their domain (cloud.tinymce.com), you should [get a free key](https://store.ephox.com/signup/) and update the URL e.g.:

```
<script src="http://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js?apiKey=[YOUR_API_KEY]"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This will remove only the first "free trial" warning notification (and leave other notifications like deprecated plugins, errors, etc).

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  init_instance_callback : function(editor) {
      var freeTiny = document.querySelector('.mce-notification');
      freeTiny.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

Comment: Same thing, You can use ```.tox-notification { display: none !important }```. Its saved me.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of avoiding the warning is to host the library yourself, as pointed out in [Nathan Goings' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71927525/466761) (which IMO should be the accepted one).

If you are integrating TinyMCE in an Angular project using the [@tinymce/tinymce-angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tinymce/tinymce-angular) package, you can override the library source path by defining a provider:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TINYMCE_SCRIPT_SRC } from '@tinymce/tinymce-angular';
import { RawEditorOptions } from 'tinymce';

@Component({
  selector: 'tiny-editor',
  template: '<editor [init]="editorOptions"></editor>',
  providers: [
    { provide: TINYMCE_SCRIPT_SRC, useValue: 'assets/tinymce.min.js' }
  ]
})
export class TinyEditorComponent   {

  editorOptions: RawEditorOptions = {
    base_url: '/assets',
    height: 500,
    menubar: false,
    plugins: [
      'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
      'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
      'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount'
    ].join(' '),
    toolbar:
      `undo redo | formatselect | bold italic backcolor |
      alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify |
      bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat | help`
  }
}
```

Don't forget to update the architect build step in your `angular.json` file, to include the tinymce files into your public assets folder:

```json
{
...
    "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "assets": [
              ...
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "./node_modules/tinymce/",
                "output": "./assets/"
              }
              ...
           ]
        }
        ...
     }
     ...
}
```

For more information, check [this guide](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/angular/) on how to integrate a self-hosted TinyMCE instance in an Angular app.

Answer (score 0):

While  CCS does the job in most cases, you may have to use `!important`. You could also try hiding it on `DOMContentLoaded` with vanilla javascript:

```
<style>
/* one way */
  .tox-notifications-container{
      visibility: hidden;
    }
/* another way */
  .tox-notifications-container{
      display: none;
    }
</style>

/* javascript way */

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
document.querySelector('.tox-notifications-container').style.visibility = "hidden";
}); // Assuming that you have only one element with this class.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had multiple textarea in same page,a called:

```
tinymce.init({
   selector: 'textarea'
})
```

Then I did in CSS

```
.tox-notifications-container{
  display: none;
}
```