# Where to add Tinymce api key?

Tags: django, tinymce

i downloaded the zip file form tinymce.cloud. and added the file in static folder everything is working fine,
except now i'm
[image: domain is not registered editor]

getting this notification every time i want to create a post.
I already have an account but as they suggested to add key in tinymce.js file the content is totally different in mine because i'm not using just single js file but bunch of files now i don't know where i should put my api key. so it stop giving me notification.

script file i'm using in head file
[image: script file]

post_create.html where i added script.

[image: post create html script file]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run TinyMCE 5 from the cloud, use the following code in the head of your HTML file, replacing `no-api-key` with your own API key:

```
<script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/no-api-key/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
```

There's more information about getting started with TinyMCE 5 on the cloud in the docs: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/quick-start/

Comment: i already tried that it's only working with (cloud/tinymce.com/stable) above script.

Comment: What happens if you try the code I suggested but specifying version 4 instead of 5? For example: `<script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/no-api-key/tinymce/4/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>`

Comment: yeah it's working with tinymce/4 but the api key is still on 30 days trial. There are others posts like we can remove the notification area do you know about that. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50038470/tinymce-shows-error-in-the-editor)

Comment: The free API key is always free, even after 30 days. The 30 day trial period relates to the use of premium plugins only. You can try any of the premium plugins for 30 days. After the 30 days, you can still use the API key to load the editor and any of the core plugins. You just won't have access to any of the premium ones.

Comment: Note that online services for version 4 of TinyMCE are being phased out in the coming months. So you might be better off upgrading to version 5.

Read more here: https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/how-to-migrate-from-tinymce-4-to-tinymce-5

Answer (score 0):

Valeria from TinyMCE is here. Please note that all editors on our cloud platform are required (from early 2024) to have a valid API key. Without a valid API key, your editor will transition to read-only mode, limiting your ability to make changes.

You can learn more here: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/invalid-api-key/

Comment: This might have been better left as a comment, as this doesn't answer the user's original question

Comment: Thanks! I just joined Stack Overflow, and it seems I can't comment because I must have 50 reputation. I tried to click Add a comment and got a notification about it.